# Dynamically append link buttons inside a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Using jquery I am trying to append JQM link buttons inside a div container.  The link buttons are displayed only once and next time onwards it is displayed as simple anchors.

HTML Page

```
<div id='pg_menu' data-role="page"> 
  <div data-role="content" id="pg_menu_content">

  </div>
</div>
```

The objective is to load link butons dynamically inside #pg_menu_content.

Jquery Code

```
function loadMenuPage(){
  $('#pg_menu_content').empty();
  $('#pg_menu_content').append("<div data-role='fieldcontain'><a href='a' data-role='button'>A</a></div>");
  $('#pg_menu_content').append("<div data-role='fieldcontain'><a href='b' data-role='button'>B</a></div>");
  $('#pg_menu_content').append("<div data-role='fieldcontain'><a href='c' data-role='button'>C</a></div>");
  $.mobile.changePage('#pg_menu');
}
```

When the method loadMenuPage is called for the first time all the 3 link buttons are displayed correctly.  But when the same function triggered for the second time (browser back button clicked and comming back) the buttons are displayed like native anchors.

What could be the problem?

Comment: `$("<a href='b' data-role='button'>B</a>").button().appendTo.('#pg_menu_content');` or append items on `pagebeforecreate` event.

Comment: Thanks Omar.  After I put inside pagebeforecreate the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append new items on `pagebeforecreate` in order to have them enhanced with JQM styles, or enhance them manually before you append them.

```
$("<a href='b' data-role='button'>B</a>").button().appendTo('#pg_menu_content');
```

Answer (score 1):

You got to tell jQuery Mobile that your created element is a button. You got to use `button()` method.

```
function loadMenuPage(){
  $('#pg_menu_content').empty();
  $div = $('<div data-role="fieldcontain"/>');
  $('<a href="a" data-role="button">A</a>').button().appendTo($div.clone()).appendTo('#pg_menu_content');
  $('<a href="b" data-role="button">B</a>').button().appendTo($div.clone()).appendTo('#pg_menu_content');
  $('<a href="C" data-role="button">C</a>').button().appendTo($div.clone()).appendTo('#pg_menu_content');
  $.mobile.changePage('#pg_menu');
}
```